# tcp retransmission response time

Tags: linux, tcp

I have the following situation:

1. Client sends a tcp retransmission request packet.
2. Server ACKs the retransmission request.
3. Server sends again the packet the client asked in the retransmission.

Between steps 1) and 2) delta time is 0.001 sec but between 2) and 3) delta time is 0.7 sec (too long)
This is only happening with the response to a retransmission packet.

My question is: Is the retransmission response time configurable?

Comment: What is (2)? ACKs aren't ACKed.

Comment: Regarding the question *"Is the retransmission response time configurable"*, I believe TCP/IP requires 3 timers (there may be more in an implementation). There is a timer for retransmission, and the timeout is likely configurable. But its probably a kernel or system option. I don't recall seeing a userland or per-socket setting. See, for example, [TCP Timeout and Retransmission](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_time.htm) and [How to modify the TCP/IP maximum retransmission time-out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170359/how-to-modify-the-tcp-ip-maximum-retransmission-time-out) on MSDN.